# Athena and S3 Inventory. HIVE_BAD_DATA: Field size's type LONG in ORC is incompatible with type varchar defined in table schema

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, storage, inventory

I'm trying to understand how to work with s3 inventory.
I'm following this [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html)

After loading inventory lists into my table I'm trying to query it and find two issues.

1) `SELECT key, size FROM table;`
Size column for all records show a magic number(value) 4923069104295859283

2) `select * from table;`
Query Id: `cf07c309-c685-4bf4-9705-8bca69b00b3c`.

Receiving error:

```
HIVE_BAD_DATA: Field size's type LONG in ORC is incompatible with type varchar defined in table schema
```

Here is my table schema:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `table`(
`bucket` string, 
`key` string, 
`version_id` string, 
`is_latest` boolean, 
`is_delete_marker` boolean, 
`size` bigint, 
`last_modified_date` timestamp, 
`e_tag` string, 
`storage_class` string)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
`dt` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.SymlinkTextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
's3://......../hive'
TBLPROPERTIES (
'transient_lastDdlTime'='1516093603')
```

Comment: Having same issue (with boolean field)

Comment: Get the exact same error

Answer (score 5):

The following command of any of your orc file coming from the inventory generated by AWS S3 will give you the actual structure of your inventory:

```
$> hive --orcfiledump ~/Downloads/017c2014-1205-4431-a30d-2d9ae15492d6.orc
...
Processing data file /tmp/017017c2014-1205-4431-a30d-2d9ae15492d6.orc [length: 4741786]
Structure for /mp/017c2014-1205-4431-a30d-2d9ae15492d6.orc
File Version: 0.12 with ORC_135
Rows: 223473
Compression: ZLIB
Compression size: 262144
Type: struct<bucket:string,key:string,size:bigint,last_modified_date:timestamp,e_tag:string,storage_class:string,is_multipart_uploaded:boolean,replication_status:string,encryption_status:string>
...
```

It appears that the example provided by aws [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html#storage-inventory-athena-query) expects that your inventory is not just for the `current version` but for `all versions` of objects in your bucket.

The right table structure for `Athena` is then for an encrypted bucket:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE inventory(
  bucket string,
  key string,
  version_id string,
  is_latest boolean,
  is_delete_marker boolean,
  size bigint,
  last_modified_date timestamp,
  e_tag string,
  storage_class string,
  is_multipart_uploaded boolean,
  replication_status string,
  encryption_status string
  )
  PARTITIONED BY (dt string)
  ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.SymlinkTextInputFormat'
  OUTPUTFORMAT  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
  LOCATION 's3://............/hive'
  TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='true');
```

Comment: Cant thank you enough for this answer. I was really struggling with this. Now we are ready to roll! https://www.dropbox.com/s/lts40z1tgtrqpwe/Screenshot%202018-11-25%2013.45.23.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

The error in our case was using 'Current Version' only in the configuration. The difference between 'current' and 'all' versions configuration is the absence of  columns:

- version_id
- is_latest
- is_delete_marker

**Example hive output for ORC format:**

```
> hive --orcfiledump ./inventoryexamplefilewithcurrentversiononly.orc
Type: struct<bucket:string,key:string,size:bigint,last_modified_date:timestamp,e_tag:string,storage_class:string,is_multipart_uploaded:boolean,replication_status:string,encryption_status:string,object_lock_retain_until_date:timestamp,object_lock_mode:string,object_lock_legal_hold_status:string>
```

**Create the table for the ORC format:**

```
-- Create table IF USING 'CURRENT VERSION' only in S3 inventory config
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE your_table_name(
  `bucket` string,
  key string,
  size bigint,
  last_modified_date timestamp,
  e_tag string,
  storage_class string,
  is_multipart_uploaded boolean,
  replication_status string,
  encryption_status string,
  object_lock_retain_until_date timestamp,
  object_lock_mode string,
  object_lock_legal_hold_status string
  )
  PARTITIONED BY (dt string)
  ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
  STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.SymlinkTextInputFormat'
  OUTPUTFORMAT  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
  LOCATION 's3://.../hive/';
```

---

Also, as an aside, if you're using "SSE-KMS" (i.e. your own KMS key) and not "SSE-S3" encryption, you don't need 'has_encrypted_data' configured.

> **Note**
>
> With SSE-KMS, Athena does not require you to indicate that data is encrypted when creating a table.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/encryption.html